VS generated Blazor WebAssembly app using Azure B2C is showing AADB2C90205
I am trying to get a local web app on my development machine to use Azure B2C for user accounts, but I am encountering an error code that seems to be 'right out of the box ', which is quite frustrating.
Using Visual Studio Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) (Version 17.9.5), on a Windows 11 machine, I created a new Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App (.Net 8.0, with Authentication type=Microsoft Identity Platform).
Upon creating the project, VS asked me to connect to my Azure account so that it could create a B2C tenant and make the necessary connections. Everything looked good and was completed successfully.
When I run the app, it shows me the sample Blazor web app. I click the Login hyperlink, and a popup browser window shows me Azure B2C, where I can create a new account or log in.
Creating a new account successfully creates a new User Account in my Azure B2C account.
After I log in or create a new user account, it redirects to my locally hosted web app.
Then it shows the following message:
There was an error trying to log you in: 'undefined - [undefined]: AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation. 
Correlation ID: a33b8507-93f9-475d-b9ed-b2c8554b0db7 Timestamp: 2024-04-22 21:50:20Z - Correlation ID: undefined - Trace ID: undefined'

All of this was generated from VS prompts, so I hoped it would work without debugging or modification. I suspect I need to go into Azure and add some permission to the tenant, but I'm not sure where or what to do. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I created Blazor WebAssembly Standalone app .net 8 and selected Authentication type as Microsoft Identity Platform.
I added this line @attribute [Authorize] to the Counter.razor page.
Below is my complete Counter.razor page.
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

Upon running my app, I faced the same issue, so I unchecked the Access Token and ID Token options under Authentication in App Registration, as shown below.

Ensure that your redirect URL is correct.

If you add Microsoft graph permission in ApI permissions grant the admin consent as shown below.

Output:

